# Extract the smallest number of dependencies for a given Windows program

Tags: windows, dependencies

On Windows, I want to package [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) with the smallest amount of binaries. I found a way to determine the dependencies but it's a little cumbersome because it requires 2 computers and a OneDrive account.

I process this way: I extract all the binaries from [the following website](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/) in a new directory in the OneDrive folder. The OneDrive client will upload all the files in the cloud. I take my second computer, go to the newly created QEMU folder. All the files are *available*, are ready to *download-on-demand* but are not physically present on the disk. Then, I execute the QEMU program I need, OneDrive will download all the files necessary for the execution of the QEMU program, one by one. When QEMU is started, I just close it and then, I delete all the files from the QEMU folder which have not been downloaded yet (their icon is different).

It's a slow, annoying process which require 2 computers, is there a better way?

I expect some kind of answers such as "don't do that, it's pointless to do that work to simply save some disk space", but I am quite interested to know more about it, to understand a little better how work some of the programs I use.

Comment: There's a sysinternals/Microsoft tool called DependancyWalker which will help with this, but it'll say things like `abc.dll`, `def.dll`, and you need to know where those come from. The listed DLL's will also have dependencies on other DLL's. The safest bet is to install the latest .net Framework, and C++ redist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method to get a list of all the DLLs used by a process:

- Download and install
  [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
- Run Process Explorer as Administrator
- View the DLLs by setting menu *View > Show Lower Pane* and
  *View > Lower Pane View > DLLs*
- Right-click the headers in the lower pane and select "Select Columns..."
- Leave selected only Name and Path and click OK
- Click the Path column to sort it
- Find and click the QEMU process
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to store a text file with all the
  displayed data
- Edit the file in a text-editor, scroll down to the DLLs and extract
  only the ones from the QEMU folder
- Repeat this for any other QEMU executable that you might see
  running.

Note that this method won't find one-time executables that QEMU might
have invoked (if there are any).

Comment: Fantastic! Note that the generated file format depends on the elements displayed in the User Interface. You can modify the output by activating/deactivating the display of specific columns. It's very handy for scripting.

Comment: Note that this solution is inferior to the OneDrive's initial solution for the following reason: it does not take in account the resources files (images, external files, configuration files, etc) it only deal with the DLLs.

Comment: On Linux, one might probably use strace and monitor all the open syscall, regardless if it is DLL or resource file, but on Windows I don't know.